# Why is the compiler generating different instructions for my SSE class and the intrinsic in debug?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, sse

*(using Visual C++ 19.00.23918, compiling in debug with optimizations turned off)*

I created a class wrapper for the __m128 intrinsic like so:

```
class alignas(16) V4Xm
{
public:

    inline constexpr V4Xm()
        : _mFoo({0}){
    }

    inline V4Xm(float X, float Y, float Z, float W)
        : _mFoo(_mm_setr_ps(X, Y, Z, W)) {
    }

    inline V4Xm(const V4Xm& Other) :
        _mFoo(Other._mFoo) {
    }

    inline V4Xm(const __m128& Intrinsic) :
        _mFoo(Intrinsic) {
    }

    inline V4Xm operator*(const V4Xm& Other) const {
        return(V4Xm(_mm_mul_ps(_mFoo, Other._mFoo)));
    }

private:
    __m128 _mFoo;
};
```

And tried to compare simple cases in debug to see what the difference was to the compiler when it generated assembly code between my inline class and the raw __m128 somewhat like this:

```
V4Xm Bar(const V4Xm& A) {
    return(A * A);
}

__m128 Bar(const __m128& A) {
    return(_mm_mul_ps(A, A));
}


int main()
{ 
    V4Xm A(1, 1, 1, 1);
    A = Bar(A);

    __m128 B(_mm_setr_ps(1, 1, 1, 1));
    B = Bar(B);

    return(0);
}
```

This generated first for my class:

```
    V4Xm A(1, 1, 1, 1);
00A11A6A  push        ecx  
00A11A6B  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [__real@3f800000 (0A16B30h)]  
00A11A73  movss       dword ptr [esp],xmm0  
00A11A78  push        ecx  
00A11A79  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [__real@3f800000 (0A16B30h)]  
00A11A81  movss       dword ptr [esp],xmm0  
00A11A86  push        ecx  
00A11A87  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [__real@3f800000 (0A16B30h)]  
00A11A8F  movss       dword ptr [esp],xmm0  
00A11A94  push        ecx  
00A11A95  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [__real@3f800000 (0A16B30h)]  
00A11A9D  movss       dword ptr [esp],xmm0  
00A11AA2  lea         ecx,[A]  
00A11AA5  call        V4Xm::V4Xm (0A11325h)  

    A = Bar(A);
00A11AAA  lea         eax,[A]  
00A11AAD  push        eax  
00A11AAE  lea         ecx,[ebp-120h]  
00A11AB4  push        ecx  
00A11AB5  call        Bar (0A112E4h)  
00A11ABA  add         esp,8  
00A11ABD  mov         edx,dword ptr [eax]  
00A11ABF  mov         dword ptr [A],edx  
00A11AC2  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax+4]  
00A11AC5  mov         dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],ecx  
00A11AC8  mov         edx,dword ptr [eax+8]  
00A11ACB  mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],edx  
00A11ACE  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+0Ch]  
00A11AD1  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],eax
```

And fewer instructions for the intrinsic:

```
    __m128 B(_mm_setr_ps(1, 1, 1, 1));
00A11AD4  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr[__xmm@3f8000003f8000003f8000003f800000 (0A16B40h)]  
00A11ADB  movaps      xmmword ptr [ebp-140h],xmm0  
00A11AE2  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [ebp-140h]  
00A11AE9  movaps      xmmword ptr [B],xmm0  
    B = Bar(B);
00A11AED  lea         eax,[B]  
00A11AF0  push        eax  
00A11AF1  call        Bar (0A1102Dh)  
00A11AF6  add         esp,4  
00A11AF9  movaps      xmmword ptr [ebp-160h],xmm0  
00A11B00  movaps      xmm0,xmmword ptr [ebp-160h]  
00A11B07  movaps      xmmword ptr [B],xmm0
```

I'm curious to as why there is such a huge difference to the compiler between these two things in debug, my class and the intrinsic. To my eyes is the same as such an intrinsic. Why is this happening?

Also please note that this is exclusive to when compiling in debug with optimizations turned off. When I tried other tests in release the compiler always generated identical instructions for both cases.

Comment: When the code is not optimized, the result is not that good. That's the way it is!

Comment: different compilers or the same compiler with different options are not necessarily  expected to produce the same code.  particularly when debug vs release or optimization level options are the differences.

Comment: The code is different because it is going through a function call, Can you post the disassembly of `V4Xm::V4Xm(float, float, float, float)`? I bet it will match the disassembly of the direct call.

Comment: Also, `A = Bar(A)` is constructing a new object to return, and then performing an assignment, which I believe explains the code after `00A11AB5  call        Bar (0A112E4h)  `